# I am trying to use the UPDATE function in SQLite3 on Python 3 although I keep recieving errors

Tags: sqlite, python-3.x

I am not really sure why this is not working. When I try to run the any part of the loop I get sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error.

```
    con = sqlite3.connect('DatabaseName.sql')
    cur = con.cursor()

    if changes == "1":
        Fname = input("Enter new first name: ")
        Lname = input("Enter the last name of the person whom first name you wish to change: ")
        cur.execute("""UPDATE Contacts SET Fname WHERE Lname""")
        con.commit()
    elif changes == "2":
        Lname = input("Enter new last name: ")
        Fname = input("Enter the first name of the person whom last name you wish to change: ")
        cur.execute("UPDATE Contacts SET Lname WHERE Fname")
        con.commit()
    elif changes == "3":
        Phone = input("Enter new telephone number(no dashes or spaces): ")
        Fname = input("Enter the first name of the person whom telephone number you wish to change: ")
        Lname = input("Enter the last name of the person whom telephone number you wish to change: ")
        Phone = int(Phone)
        cur.execute("""UPDATE Contacts SET Phone WHERE Fname AND Lname""")
        con.commit()
```

Comment: Your sql statements are completely messed up, you should read an sql tutorial. You are missing a value for both SET and WHERE... The syntax for SET and WHERE is `fieldname=value`, as in `SET Fname="someName" WHERE Lname="someOtherName"`.

Answer (score 3):

Python and SQL are two completely indepent languages; you cannot directly access variables of one from the other.

To pass the *values* of Python variables into your SQL commands, use parameters, like this:

```py
cur.execute("UPDATE Contacts SET FirstName = ? WHERE LastName = ?", (Fname, Lname))
```

(Here, `FirstName` and `LastName` are the column names in the table, and may or may not be identical with the Python variable names.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is my first time trying to use this and the tutorials aren't much help

Comment: If you think the answer is helpful, please [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).